# On simple calculations with $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor{\frac{km}{n}}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{2}(m-1)(n-1)$ and primes $m$ and $n$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics, products, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Wikipedia's article for [Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients), relates in the section of *Quotients* that the identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor{\frac{km}{n}}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{2}(m-1)(n-1)$$
holds whenever $m$ and $n$ are positive and **coprime.**

Let $p_r$ the rth **prime number**, I wrote for $p_1=2$ and $p_2=3$ that $$\sum_{k=1}^{p_2-1}\left\lfloor{\frac{kp_1}{p_2}}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{2}(p_1-1)(p_2-1),$$ and when $N=2m$, where $m\leq 1$ is an integers, one writes also 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p_{N+1}-1}\left\lfloor{\frac{kp_N}{p_{N+1}}}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{2}(p_{N}-1)(p_{N+1}-1).$$ Then telescoping the product of consecutive quotients of all identities which one states between these extremes one proves $$(P_{N+1}-1)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{N}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{p_{2j-1}}\left\lfloor{\frac{kp_{2j-1}}{p_{2j}}}\right\rfloor\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{N}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{p_{2j+1}}\left\lfloor{\frac{kp_{2j}}{p_{2j+1}}}\right\rfloor.$$ And as consequence of the **Prime Number Theorem** then one has the asymptotic equivalence $$((N+1)\log (N+1))\left(\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{N}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{p_{2j-1}}\left\lfloor{\frac{kp_{2j-1}}{p_{2j}}}\right\rfloor\right)\sim\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{N}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{p_{2j+1}}\left\lfloor{\frac{kp_{2j}}{p_{2j+1}}}\right\rfloor,$$
as $N$ tends to infinite.

> **Question.** **a)** Please can you say me if were right my calculations? Only is required a yes/no, since **b)** can you state the similar identity and the corresponding asymptotic equivalence for the case $N=2m+1$? **Many thanks.**

Comment: Use **\left\lfloor** and **\right\rfloor** to generate the appropriate sizes of $\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$. And also, I believe this is an abandoned question and should be bumped up to the homepage. Oh, and finally, "yes".

Comment: Ok. It was strange, though, how this question did not even receive an answer at least. But the same applies for my most recent question thus far.

Comment: Many thanks @user477343 for your help.

Comment: No problemo :) ${}$